# can not find the symbol when compiling a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is my servlet code:

```
    package com.example.web;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    public class BeerSelect extends HttpServlet{
      public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response) 
          throws IOExcpetion, ServletException{
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter  out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Beer Selection Advice<br />");
        String c = request.getParameter("color");
        out.println("Got beer color " + c);
      }
    }
```

When I compile it I get the following error:

> can not find symbol   throws throws IOExcpetion, ServletException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
throws IOExcpetion
```

To:

```
throws IOException
```

Answer (score 2):

Typo: `IOExcpetion` should be `IOException`.